# command + backtick (`) not working in XCode 9

Tags: xcode

`` command + ` ``
 
doesn't switch between active documents(projects) in XCode 9.0.  I have the

`System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Keyboard -> Move focus to next window` shortcut set to `` command + ` ``

Any ideas on why it doesn't work?

Comment: That’s a System shortcut. It should work for any app. I just checked 9.2b2 and it’s not an issue there. Is something else gobbling up the keystroke?

Comment: Works in Firefox and Numbers command backtick doesn't work in XCode though...I reset the system keyboard shorcuts to the default values